How to append external VM args in gradle application plugin
I am using Gradle Application Plugin to run a main class. I know we can provide VM args using applicationDefaultJvmArgs. When I try to run the code using IntelliJ gradle run configs(or an external shell script) as gradle run by providing VM args -Dfoo=bar, they are not used in applicationDefaultJvmArgs.
How can I append external VM args to those specified in applicationDefaultJvmArgs?

You can write code (or apply a plugin if one exists) in your build script that reads JVM args from somewhere (e.g., an environment variable, a file, a system property, etc.) and adds them to applicationDefaultJvmArgs.

Project properties
You can pass in a project property using the -P flag and use that in your build script.
So if you write something in your build script like:
// Kotlin DSL

application {
    if (ext.has("jvmArg")) applicationDefaultJvmArgs += ext["jvmArg"] as String
    // other app config
}


// Groovy DSL

application {
    if (ext.has("jvmArg")) applicationDefaultJvmArgs += jvmArg
    // other app config
}

You can run that from the command line by doing the following to, eg, pass the argument "foo":
./gradlew run -PjvmArg=foo

Main class args
applicationDefaultJvmArgs works with the raw arguments being passed to the java command. If you instead want to configure just the arguments being passed to the main class it is easier to configure the run task which is added by the Application plugin.
To do that, you can instead write the following to use your command line argument:
// Kotlin DSL

tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    if (ext.has("jvmArg")) args(ext["jvmArg"] as String)
}

// Groovy DSL

tasks.named('run') {
    if (ext.has('jvmArg')) args(jvmArg)
}


Note for the run task, another way to pass application arguments is via --args on the command line.
